# Iterating Operations on elements of a List (Basic)

Tags: list-manipulation

My only programming experience is a tiny bit of Python, and so I fear I'm thinking in the wrong way about this problem.

I want to generate a sequence of lists with updating entries where the following list's entries are dependent upon the previous list's entries. The following code technically does what I need, but obviously there's an algorithmic way to do this.

```
sigma1[x_, y_] := (1 - t)*y + t*x
siginv2[x_, y_] := (1 - t^{-1})*x + t^{-1}*y

op1 = Flatten[{b, siginv2[sigma1[a, b], c], sigma1[a, b]}]
op2 = Flatten[{op1[[2]], 
   siginv2[sigma1[op1[[1]], op1[[2]]], op1[[3]]], 
   sigma1[op1[[1]], op1[[2]]]}]
op3 = Flatten[{op2[[2]], 
   siginv2[sigma1[op2[[1]], op2[[2]]], op2[[3]]], 
   sigma1[op2[[1]], op2[[2]]]}]
```

and so on...

Comment: Look at `Nest` and friends.

Comment: You should not use list brackets in place of parentheses. See [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#8720) After correcting this, the `Flatten` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decompose your problem into smaller parts. Here's a function that will do one step in the sequence:

```
ProcessStep[{e1_, e2_, e3_}] := {e2, siginv2[sigma1[e1, e2], e3], sigma1[e1, e2]}
```

("ProcessStep" is kind of lame, but I don't know what your semantics are.)

You can test it:

```
ProcessStep[{a, b, c}]
```

`{b, siginv2[sigma1[a, b], c], sigma1[a, b]}`

Now you want to apply this repeatedly. That's what Nest is for:

```
Nest[ProcessStep, {a, b, c}, 3]
```

That should give you the same result as what you called `op3`. If you want the whole "history" of results, use `NestList`:

```
NestList[ProcessStep, {a, b, c}, 3]
```

**UPDATE**

I just noticed @BobHanlon's comment. Yes, you need to replace those `{}` in your `siginv2` function for this to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
{op1b, op2b, op3b} = NestList[
  Flatten[{#[[2]], siginv2[sigma1[#[[1]], #[[2]]], #[[3]]],
     sigma1[#[[1]], #[[2]]]}] &,
  Flatten[{b, siginv2[sigma1[a, b], c], sigma1[a, b]}], 2]

{op1, op2, op3} == {op1b, op2b, op3b}
```

> True